# Two-step copy elision to capture rvalue in constructor call as instance variable

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, move-constructor, copy-elision

I am trying to get an `rvalue` instance of this class:

```
#include <iostream>
#define msg(x) std::cout << x " constructor\n"

struct X {
    int i;
    X(int i) : i(i) {msg("X");}
    X(const X& x) : i(x.i) {std::cout << "X copy\n";}
    X(X&& x) {std::swap(i, x.i); std::cout << "X move\n";}
};
```

into instance variable `x` of this class:

```
struct A {
    X x;
    A(X x) : x(x) {msg("A");}
};
```

like so:

```
int main() {
    A a(X(1));
    std::cout << a.x.i << "\n\n";
}
```

*without any copies or moves being made*.

According to these references,

- http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html
- http://www.slideshare.net/oliora/hot-11-2-new-style-arguments-passing

and many many posts on SO (*so please read to the end before flagging as duplicate*), I should rely on **copy elision**, whose conditions should be satisfied if I **pass by value**. Note that there are **two** copy elisions required, namely:

`constructor call -> constructor local variable -> instance variable`

as can be seen when turning copy elision off (compile with `g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -fno-elide-constructors`):

```
X constructor
X move
X copy
A constructor
1
```

So there is one `move` step and one `copy` step, which should both go away if I turn copy elision on (compile with `g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O3`):

```
X constructor
X copy
A constructor
1
```

Bummer, the `copy` step remained!

---

Can I get any better with any other variation of `std::move()`, `std::forward` or passing as `rvalue-reference`?

```
struct B {
    X x;
    B(X x) : x(std::move(x)) {msg("B");}
};

struct C {
    X x;
    C(X x) : x(std::forward<X>(x)) {msg("C");}
};

struct D {
    X x;
    D(X&& x) : x(std::move(x)) {msg("D");}
};

int main() {
    B b(X(2));
    std::cout << b.x.i << "\n\n";

    C c(X(3));
    std::cout << c.x.i << "\n\n";

    D d(X(4));
    std::cout << d.x.i << "\n\n";
}
```

which produces the output:

```
X constructor
X move
B constructor
2

X constructor
X move
C constructor
3

X constructor
X move
D constructor
4
```

OK, I turned the `copy` into a `move`, *but this is not satisfactory!*

---

Next, I tried to make the instance variable `x` a reference `X&`:

```
struct E {
    X& x;
    E(X x) : x(x) {msg("E");}
};

int main() {
    E e(X(5));
    std::cout << e.x.i << "\n\n";
}
```

which produces:

```
X constructor
E constructor
1690870696
```

Bad idea! I got rid of the `move` but the `rvalue` instance that `x` was referencing to got destroyed under my seat, so the last line prints garbage instead of `5`. Two notes:

- `g++-4.8` didn't warn me of anything, even with `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra`
- The program prints `5` when compiled with `-O0`

So this bug may go unnoticed for quite a while!

---

So, is this a hopeless case? Well no:

```
struct F {
    X& x;
    F(X& x) : x(x) {msg("F");}
};

int main() {
    X x(6);
    F f(x);
    std::cout << f.x.i << "\n";
}
```

prints:

```
X constructor
F constructor
6
```

Really? No fancy new `C++11` features, no copy elision at the discretion of the compiler, just plain old FORTRAN66-style pass-by-reference does what I want and probably will perform best?

**So here are my questions:**

- Is there any way one can get this to work for `rvalues`? Did I miss any features?
- Is the `lvalue`-reference version really the best, or are there hidden costs in the `X x(6)` step?
- Could there be any inconveniences introduced by `x` living on after the construction of `f`?
- Could I pay a data locality penalty for using the `lvalue` reference to an external instance?

Comment: `struct E` has undefined behaviour (dangling reference.) And `struct F` "works", but does something totally different to all the rest (bar the UB `E`). So what are you trying to compare?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, I learned the behavior of `struct E` the hard way...

Comment: Your best bet is two overloads: `T1(const T2& t) : t_(t) {}` and `T1(T2&& t) : t_(std::move(t)) {}`

Comment: @juanchopanza: All versions, including `struct F`, can fully access instance `x`, which is what I need.

Comment: No, `F` has a reference to an external entity. It doesn't own it. The others (ignoring `E`) do. This is a crucial difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going into too much detail of your question, copy elision is basically used as much as possible. Here's a quick demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct X
{
    int n_;

    explicit X(int n) : n_(n) { std::cout << "Construct: " << n_ << "\n"; }
    X(X const & rhs) : n_(rhs.n_) { std::cout << "X copy:" << n_ << "\n"; }
    X(X && rhs) : n_(rhs.n_) { rhs.n_ = -1; std::cout << "X move:" << n_ << "\n"; }
   ~X() { std::cout << "Destroy: " << n_ << "\n"; }
};

struct A
{
    explicit A(X x) : x_(std::move(x)) {};
    X x_;
};

struct B
{
    X x;
};

int main()
{
    A a(X(12));
    B b { X(24) };
}
```

This [produces](http://ideone.com/FnJLag):

```
Construct: 12
X move:12
Destroy: -1
Construct: 24
Destroy: 24
Destroy: 12
```

The one move in `x_(std::move(x))` is not elidable, since it doesn't involve a function return. But that's pretty good anyway. And notice how the aggregate `b` is indeed initialized "in-place".

---

Your example `F` shows that you're willing to expose the coupling of `X` to its ambient class. In that case, you could make a special constructor for `A` that constructs the `X` directly:

```
struct A
{
    explicit A(X x) : x_(std::move(x)) {};
    X x_;

    // Better approach
    struct direct_x_t {};
    static direct_x_t direct_x;

    // In our case, this suffices:
    A(direct_x_t, int n) : x_(n) {}

    // Generally, a template may be better: (TODO: add SFINAE control)
    template <typename ...Args> A(direct_x_t, Args &&... args)
    : x_(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};
```

Usage:

```
A a(A::direct_x, 36);
```

Comment: Thanks! So do you think `struct B` is the best? What's wrong with `struct F`, which is my favorite? :)

Comment: @Stefan: Most times you won't be able to have aggregate classes, so that may not be an option. Personally, I'm perfectly happy with `struct A` and would use that as a general model. `F` is insane; you should essentially never have reference members unless you *really* know what you're doing and are ready to support your users at 4am.

Comment: @Stefan: If you're willing to expose the coupling to `X`, you can try the alternate approach I added. It's similar to `emplace` in various standard library containers.

Comment: In my use case, I am free to use `struct F` if I want to. My evaluation suggests that this will save me one move operation. Both `x` and `f` will live in the same tiny scope.

Comment: @KerrekSB why does the struct A with forwarding mechanic allow the compiler to construct the object in-place while a constructor moving a temporary does not? Does the variadic template play a role in allowing it?

Comment: @KerrekSB - nevermind. I see now. Silly me misreading that as passing in the X(6) when its not. Its just passing through the actual construction argument that X needs (as in your Usage which I didnt pay attention to).

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'm looking into the template suggestion. My actual `rvalue` comes from a method call of another class, so I'm not sure if I can use this in this case.

Comment: @Stefan: I'm mostly certain that there'll be absolutely no measurable performance difference. Why are you trying so hard to avoid one move? And if you have a class that cannot be moved at all (e.g. a mutex), then copy elision doesn't apply anyway.

Comment: I ended up refactoring my code so that `X` is constructed inside of `A`. Thanks for your help!